# Detect load iframe when we use ajax Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I ran into an unexpected problem. In my script i must detect event load iframe, get content and make some things with iframe. I get event load iframe in next view

```
 //first_file.js
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $("iframe").on('load', function(){
          var iframe_content=$("iframe").contents();
          // doing some manipulation with iframe_content
      });
  });
```

But when i load script first_file.js with help Ajax

```
// second_file.js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $.getScript("first_file.js").done(function (script, textStatus) {

   }).fail(function (jqxhr, settings, exception) {
       console.log(exception);
   });
});
```

event

```
$("iframe").on('load', function(){
```

just not run! Why and how fix?

Comment: So where is the ajax?

Comment: If you want i can add example code with ajax loader script. But why? I just use  $.getScript

Comment: This question is asking about ajax but I don't see any ajax in the source code...

Comment: I'd assume that this is because the iframe's load event fired before the script had run, so when it bound the onload handler, it was too late.

Comment: Maybe but what i can do to fix this, if i not wish delete ajax loader ) or it's impossible?